# Is it possible to add my own toggle button to quick settings panel

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to figure out if there's any way I can add such a button programmatically that will open certain activity in my application?
my application is pre-installed and therefor have system permissions.
just to make sure , I'm talking about the quick settings button panel we have in the notification upper area.
Image for reference : http://howikis.com/Image:Notification_panel_settings04.png

another question , if the answer is no , if I can get my application signed with platform certificate , will this help?
thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That is not configurable from an ordinary SDK app. Whether there is some means of modifying the quick settings panel in your custom firmware is up to the maintainers of that custom firmware, I suppose.

Comment: That what I suspected ,
Thanks.